# Finding out cache misses when using mmap

Tags: python, linux, mmap

I need to perform searches in quite large files. The search operations need random access (think of binary search), and I will `mmap` the files for ease of use and performance. The search algorithm takes the page size into account so that whenever I need to access some memory area, I will try to make the most of it. Due to this there are several parameters to tune. I would like to find the parameters which give me the *least number of reads from the block device*.

I can do this with pen and paper, but the theoretical work carries only so far. The practical environment with a lot happening and different page caches is more complex. There are several processes accessing the files, and certain pages may usually be available in the file system page cache due to other activity on the files. (I assume the OS is aware of these when using `mmap`.)

In order to see the actual performance of my search algorithms in terms of number of blocks read from the block device, I would need to know the number of page misses occurring during my `mmap` accesses.

A dream-com-true solution would be one that would tell me which pages of the memory area are in the cache already. A very good solution would be a function which tells me whether a given page is in the real memory. This would both enable me to tune the parameters and possibly even be part of my algorithm ("if this page is in real memory, we'll extract some information out of it, if it isn't then we'll read another page").

The system will run on Linux (3-series kernel), so if there is no OS-agnostic answer, Linux-specific answers are acceptable. The benchmark will be written in python, but if the interfaces exist only in C, then I'll live with that.

**Example**

Let us have a file with fixed record length records carrying a sorted identifier and some data. We want to extract the data between some starting and ending position (as defined by the identifiers. The trivial solution is to use binary search to find the start position and then return everything until the end is reached.

However, the situation changes somewhat if we need to take cacheing into account. Then direct memory accesses are essentially free but page misses are expensive. A simple solution is to use binary search to find any position within the range. Then the file can be traversed backwards till the start position is reached. Then the file is traversed to the forward direction until the end is reached. This sounds quite stupid, but it ensures that once a single point within the range is found, no extra pages need to be loaded.

So, the essential thing is to find a single position within the range. Binary search is a good candidate, but if we know that, for example, the three last or three first pages of the file are usually in the page cache anyway, we should use that information, as well. If we knew which of the pages are in the cache, the search algorithm could be made much better, but even with *a posteriori* knowledge whether we hit or missed helps.

(The actual problem is a bit more complicated than that, but maybe this illustrates the need.)

**Partial solution:**

As JimB tells in his answer, there is no such API in Linux. That leaves us with more generic profiling tools (such as python's `cProfile` or `perf stat` in Linux).

The challenge with my code is that I know most of the time will be spent with the memory accesses which end up being cache misses. This is very easy, as they are the only points where the code may block. In the code I have something like `b = a[i]`, and this will either be very fast or very slow depending on `i`.

Of course, seeing the total number of cache misses during the running time of the process may help with some optimizations, but I would really know if the rest of the system creates a situation where, e.g. first or last pages of the file are most of the time in the cache anyway.

So, I will implement timing of the critical memory accesses (ones that may miss the cache). As almost everything running in the system is I/O-limited (not CPU limited), it is unlikely that a context switch would too often spoil my timing.  This is not an ideal solution, but it seems to be the least bad one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really something that needs to be handled outside of your program. The virtual memory layer is handled by the kernel, and the details are not exposed to the process itself. You can profile your program within its process, and estimate what's happening based on the timing of your function calls, but to really see what's going on you needs to use OS specific profiling tools.

Linux has a great tool for this: [`perf`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org). The `perf stat` command may be all you need to get an overview of how your program is executing.

Comment: This was what I was afraid of! I tried to be lazy and not to add large amount of profiling code into my program, but it seems that timing the calls is then the best alternative. `perf` is good, but in this case I would have needed the per process stats in real time (which I couldn't figure out how to squeeze out of `perf`). Anyway, it is a valuable piece of information that there is no API to find out whether a page is in the physical memory or not, thank you!

Comment: @DrV: you might be able to get good profiling info using the python `cProfile` module (versus writing timing info directly in your code). But, since your model depends on previous runs, and/or external processes reading data into the page cache, OS level tools are the way to go.

Comment: I added more information to my question to explain why the generic profiling tools seem a bit lacking here. Of course, it may be that it is my thinking that is lacking, and in that case I am grateful for all suggestions!